# I want to know how to use LUIS region key

Tags: azure, authorization, azure-language-understanding

I use free subscription ID.

I made LUIS resource and region was 'Asia Regions'.

When I entered LUIS.ai homepage, there was a westus starter key.

I added 'Asia Regions' key in the 'Publish' tab and entered model ID and subscription key into my code.

But it didn't work.

Only 'North America Regions' starter key worked.

I want to use asia key which I made in Azure portal.

How can I use this key?

Comment: Have you created the Asia region key under the same subscription key which you are trying to use. Please check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/manage-keys#assign-endpoint-key

Comment: Yes. When I go to Publish -> Resource and Keys -> Asia Regions , an Endpoint exists. It is like  https://eastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/xxxxxxxxx?subscription-key=xxxxxxxxxx&verbose=true&timezoneOffset=0&q=

Comment: When I click that endpoint it works well.
The message says : {"query":null,"intents":[],"entities":[]} Is it good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using the endpoint directly from the publish without adding query which is giving you null result.

If you are constructing your endpoint URLs for your LUIS-calling application, **make sure these same routes and query string values are set for the endpoint used** -- if you want them set as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/publishapp#endpoint-url-construction).

Comment: I somehow figured it out... I had to add these words: domain:"eastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com" in [LuisModel()] which west.us doesn't need these. Thank you.